# Swagger on Spring boot - How do I set example value for a POST method that requires a parameter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-2.0

I have a POST method `/predict`

```
public ResponseEntity predict(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> inputs) {...}
```

Right now on Swagger UI I only see empty Map under `Example Value`
[image]

I have a class called `RequestInput` that has the structure for the inputs. But however I cannot do

```
public ResponseEntity predict(@RequestBody RequestInput requestInput) {...}
```

Because `Map<String, Object> inputs` is an expected input for the POST request. I tried

```
public ResponseEntity predict(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> inputs, @RequestBody RequestInput requestInput) {...}
```

It will show `RequestInput` in the `Example Value` but the prediction will fail because it detected `RequestInput` as the param and it will throw `nullpointerexception`

Comment: using [`@ExampleProperty`](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/springfox-spring-web/src/test/java/springfox/documentation/spring/web/dummy/controllers/FeatureDemonstrationService.java#L269)

Answer (score 0):

You can use add `@ApiParam` annotation something like

```java
public ResponseEntity predict(@ApiParam(defaultValue = "{\"key\":\"value\"}") @RequestBody Map<String, Object> inputs) {...}
```

Comment: is there a way to make use of RequstInput.class? because @ApiParam defaultValue only accepts String, it might be messy if the input structure is big